# How to display data on blade from Vue Js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I had grabbed some code for test purpose, I have tried to fixing "item not define" error but I am stuck.

```
//Blade View
<v-app id="app" v-cloak><div class="card" :posts="{{$posts}}"></div></v-app>

//Vuejs template
<table striped hover :items="imageList"> <img :scr="'/storage/image/'+data.items.image"></table>
```

Vue Js:

```
<script>
export default {
  //  name: "ExampleComponent",
     props: \['posts'\],
    data() {
        return {
            imageList: \[\]
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        const fetch = this.fetch_image_list();
    },
    methods: {
        fetch_image_list() {
            let items = \[\];
            if (Array.isArray(this.posts.data) && this.posts.length.data) {
                this.posts.data.forEach((post, key) => {
                    let currentImage = {
                        id: post.id,
                        name: post.name,
                        image: post.img
                    };
                    items.push(currentImage);
                });
                this.imageList = items;
            }
        }
    }
};
</script>]
```

[item is not define](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6lUT.jpg)

Comment: how was your project set up?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it because you are "calling" :
`data.items.image` instead of `items[index].image` ?